# How to read a .desktop file to get icon file path?

Tags: javascript

I have a .desktop file and I want to read the icon png image file path in javascript so I can display it in my html file. How would I go about doing this?

This is what my .desktop file looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=BackMeUp
Comment=Back up your data with one click
Exec=/home/alex/Documents/backup.sh
Icon=/home/alex/Pictures/backup.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `javascript` you saying is only the javascript in browser, it's impossible except you upload the file to a server and analyze it.

#### 1.browser javascript and server

First of all you should have a `form` that you can upload your `.desktop` file, and then you upload to a server(you can use `node.js` to build a server).

After the server received it, you can read its content as text and find the line of `Icon` and then response to browser

#### 2. serverside javascript: node.js

if you can use `node.js` for reading this file, it's much easier.

just install `node.js` and build a `.js` file and use `fs.readFileSync` to read the `.desktop` file and analyze it line by line.